Does $\int_{\mathbb R^d} (1+|x|^{1 + \alpha}) \ell (x) \, d x < \infty$ imply $\int_{\mathbb R^d} (1+|x|) |\ell (x)|^{1-\alpha} \, d x < \infty$?
$
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
$
We fix $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. Let $\ell : \bR^d \to \bR_+$ be a continuous function such that
$$
\|\ell\|_{\infty} + \sup_{\substack{x, y \in {\bR}^d \\ x \neq y}} \frac{| \ell (x)-\ell (y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} + \int_{\bR^d} (1+|x|^{1 + \alpha}) \ell (x) \diff x < \infty.
$$
Is it true that
$$
\int_{\bR^d} (1+|x|) |\ell (x)|^{1 - \alpha} \diff x < \infty \, ? 
$$
Thank you for your elaboration.

I don't think the regularity assumptions on $\ell$ will help anything, as the core of the question is really just about decay and you can modify counterexamples to be of bounded and Holder continuous nature with the same decay properties.
What do you then think about $\ell(x) \sim \vert x\vert^{-1-\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}$ for large $\vert x\vert$ ($d=1$)?

Unwissen's answer in comments already provides a negative answer to the question, but I thought I would record here a general technique for resolving the broader class of questions of this type.  For such problems, I find it useful to heuristically view a given function such as $\ell : {\mathbb R}^d \to {\mathbb R}_+$ as being largely described by a small number of key statistics, including:

The amplitude $A$ of the function (how large the function typically is on its typical support);
The width $W$ of its (essential) support;
The distance $R$ of its support from the origin (this is only relevant in cases, such as this one, where weights such as $|x|$ depending on this distance emerge); and
The frequency $N$ of oscillation of this function (or, equivalently, the wavelength $1/N$ of the function).  This quantity is only relevant if some regularity hypotheses, such as Holder or Sobolev norm bounds, are in play.

(See also this blog post of mine for more discussion of these parameters in the context of dispersive PDE.)
These quantities are somewhat imprecisely defined, but their meaning should be intuitively clear.  An example of a function $\ell$ with the indicated parameters might be something like a "wave packet"
$$ \ell(x) = (1 + \cos(N x \cdot \omega)) A \varphi\left( \frac{x-x_0}{W} \right)$$
where $\omega$ is some direction, $\varphi$ is some bump function, and $x_0$ is some location of magnitude $|x_0| \sim R$ (the addition by one here is only imposed because the OP required $\ell$ to be non-negative).
There are some heuristic constraints between these (informal) parameters; for instance, the uncertainty principle indicates that one should have $NW \gg 1$ or equivalently $W \gg 1/N$ (the width has to exceed the wavelength), and if one wants the entire support to stay a comparable distance from the origin one also would like to have $W \ll R$.
The point of introducing these (informal) quantities is that most of the expressions that appear in a functional inequality can be expressed as some combination of powers of these quantities.  For instance, in the regime where $NW \gg 1$ and $R \gg W, 1$:

$\|\ell\|_\infty$ is basically just $A$.
$\sup_{\stackrel{x,y \in {\mathbb R}^d}{x \neq y}} \frac{|\ell(x)-\ell(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}$ is basically just $\frac{A}{(1/N)^\alpha}$ (the dominant contribution comes when the separation $|x-y|$ between two points is comparable to the wavelength $1/N$).
$\int_{{\mathbb R}^d} (1+|x|^{1+\alpha}) \ell(x)\ dx$ is basically $R^{1+\alpha} A W^d$.
$\int_{{\mathbb R}^d} (1 + |x|) |\ell(x)|^{1-\alpha}\ dx$ is basically $R A^{1-\alpha} W^d$.

So the question now becomes basically an algebra question: if $NW \gg 1$ and $R \gg W, 1$ are such that $A$, $\frac{A}{(1/N)^\alpha}$, and $R^{1+\alpha} A W^d$ are bounded, does this imply that $R A^{1-\alpha} W^d$ is also bounded?  (Here we have substituted "bounded" for "finite"; in practice the two are interchangeable thanks to facts such as the uniform boundedness principle or closed graph theorem, but since this is a heuristic discussion anyway, I will gloss over this point.)
One can simplify this problem by eliminating variables.  As pointed out by unwissen in comments, the regularity hypothesis plays no essential role: without loss of generality one can take $N$ to be as small as possible, that is to say $N = 1/W$, and then the bound on $\frac{A}{(1/N)^\alpha}$ is subsumed by the bound on $A$ as long as $W \gg 1$, which seems a reasonable hypothesis to adopt.  So now we are asking: if $R \gg W \gg 1$, and $A$ and $R^{1+\alpha} A W^d$ are both bounded, is it true that $R A^{1-\alpha} W^d$  is also bounded?
Now that $R$ and $W$ are both assumed larger than $1$, the bound on $R^{1+\alpha} A W^d$ subsumes the bound on $A$, so we are now trying to see whether the bound $R^{1+\alpha} A W^d = O(1)$ implies $R A^{1-\alpha} W^d = O(1)$.  It is clear now that we may assume without loss of generality that $A$ attains its maximal value of $R^{-(1+\alpha)} W^{-d}$, so substituting this in, we are asking whether
$$ R (R^{-(1+\alpha)} W^{-d})^{1-\alpha} W^d = R^{\alpha^2} W^{d\alpha}$$
is bounded for $R \gg W \gg 1$.  But this is clearly false: taking for instance $R=W$ to be large, we see that this expression goes to infinity as $R$ goes to infinity.
Having done this heuristic analysis to arrive at a predicted negative answer, one can now reverse all the steps to figure out an actual counterexample.  The analysis predicts that we should take $R=W$, $A = R^{-(1+\alpha)} W^{-d} = R^{-d-1-\alpha}$, and $N = 1/W$, leading to a candidate function basically of the form
$$ \ell(x) := R^{-d-1-\alpha} \eta(x/R)$$
where $\eta$ is some bump function cutoff to the annulus $\{ x: |x| \sim 1 \}$.  Here, one can confirm that all the terms in
$$ \| \ell\|_\infty + \sup_{\stackrel{x,y \in {\mathbb R}^d}{x \neq y}} \frac{|\ell(x)-\ell(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} + \int_{{\mathbb R}^d} (1 + |x|) |\ell(x)|^{1-\alpha}\ dx$$
are bounded, while the expression
$$\int_{{\mathbb R}^d} (1 + |x|) |\ell(x)|^{1-\alpha}\ dx$$
is of size $R^{d+1} R^{-(d+1+\alpha)(1-\alpha)} = R^{\alpha (d+\alpha)}$.  This already shows that boundedness of the former expression does not imply boundedness of the latter; to get from this to the statement for finiteness, one can stack an infinite number of these dyadically localized examples together (adding an epsilon decay factor to make the former expression converge); for instance,
$$ \ell(x) := (1+|x|)^{-d-1-\alpha-\varepsilon}$$
will provide a counterexample to your statement for sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$ (the example provided by unwissen is basically of this type).
I recommend as an exercise to interpret standard inequalities in analysis, such as the Sobolev inequality, Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality, or Holder inequality, using this sort of heuristic analysis (which one can think of as a fancier version of dimensional analysis).

Thank you! ${}{}{}$

Thank you very much for your informative answer.
